# Indexing data by string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv file with columns that encode the name and index of the array below. eg:

```
time, dataset1[0], dataset1[1], dataset1[2], dataset2[0], dataset2[1], dataset2[2]\n
0, 43, 35, 29, 21, 59, 39\n
1, 21, 59, 39, 43, 35, 29\n
```

You get the idea (obviously there is far more data in the arrays).

Any ideas how can I easily parse/strip this into an efficient dataframes?

[EDIT]

Ideally I'm after a structure like this:

```
    time  dataset1   dataset2
0    0   [43,35,29]  [21,59,39]
1    1   [21,59,39]  [43,35,29]
```

where the index's have been stripped from the labels and turned into nparray indices.

Answer (score 2):

```
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv('data.csv')

print df
```

Gives as output:

```
>>> 
   time   dataset1[0]   dataset1[1]   dataset1[2]   dataset2[0]   dataset2[1]  \
0     0            43            35            29            21            59   
1     1            21            59            39            43            35   

   dataset2[2]  
0           39  
1           29
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the indices stripped from the column labels to form array indices (would make it easier).  I've clarified this a little in the OP.

Comment: @AndyM Can you show the code of what you have tried yourself and where you are stuck?

Comment: I don't really have any code for this as I can't work out how to do it.  Whether I should be trying to split the string by the opening square bracket.  As it stands I can visually inspect the file and tailor a script for each file (ignoring the headers), but I wondered if there was a clever easy way.